# Iterate through ip address range in perl

Tags: perl, ipv4

I have to iterate through a range of ip addresses in perl and print a list of all ip's in that range. for ex - for

```
192.168.122.1-192.168.122.4
```

My return value is

```
192.168.122.1, 192.168.122.2, 192.168.122.3, 192.168.122.4
```

Also I cannot use `Net::IP` or `Netmask` modules, so finding other ways to iterate.

Following solution works but has some problems i cant seem to figure out -

1 - my start and end would be perl variables "" and not as mentioned in the code below. The code below doesnt work with start="192.168.122.1"

2 - How can i get a list of all ips appended at the end?

```
sub inc_ip { $_[0] = pack "N", 1 + unpack "N", $_[0] }
my $start = 192.168.122.1;
my $end = 192.168.122.4;
for ( $ip = $start; $ip le $end; inc_ip($ip) ) {
    printf "%vd\n", $ip;
}
```

Comment: What makes you say that you cannot use `Net::IP` or `Net::Netmask`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
use Socket 'inet_aton';
my $start = "192.168.122.1";
my $end = "192.168.122.4";
my @x = map { sprintf "%vi", pack "N", $_ } unpack("N",inet_aton($start)) .. unpack("N",inet_aton($end));
use DDP; p @x;
```

Comment: Yes inet_aton and inet_ntoa. Just got the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [Net::IP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::IP). From the CPAN documentation:

```
use Net::IP;
my $ip = new Net::IP ('195.45.6.7 - 195.45.6.19') || die;
# Loop
do {
    print $ip->ip(), "\n";
} while (++$ip);
```

This approach is more flexible because Net::IP accepts CIDR notation e.g. 193.0.1/24 and also supports IPv6.